# How is it that the Cells() property accepts decimal values?

Tags: excel, vba

If I execute the following code

```
Cells(3.0004, 5.604).Interior.ColorIndex = 1
```

it will color the cell at Row 3, Column 6 (F3) black. It does so without complaining and appears to silently round the values. How and why?

Comment: Cells is of type Range, for which default property is item that takes (variant type ) row and column index. When you are providing integral type as the parameter, excel is trying to convert it to integer or may be long to get a valid index (can't  say for sure) and as there are no issues in conversion, it works fine.  clng(5.604) or cint(5.604) is 6.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Range.Cells` property is parameterless.

[image: Property Cells As Range / read-only / member of Excel.Range]

This means `Cells(foo, bar)` is an implicit default member call which resolves to something like this (assuming the code is written in a standard module):

```
 ActiveSheet.Cells.[_Default](foo, bar)
```

[image: hidden Range._Default property]

If the default member is invoked without parameters, what you get is a member call to the range's `Value`.

If the default member is invoked *with* parameters, what you get is a member call to the range's `Item` property:

[image: range.item property]

The `RowIndex` and `ColumnIndex` parameters are `Variant`, so you can give it "D" for a column and it understands you want the 4th. Or you can give it any integer value and it'll work with that.

So why is it happy to work with a decimal value? Because it's forgiving, that's all: it makes the implicit narrowing type conversion from `Double` to `Long`, and merrily takes `5.604` and makes that `6`.